# How do I get pgAdmin4's result grid to load all results?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When I run a query in pgAdmin4 that returns several thousand rows, I can only scroll down a short way in the result grid.  If I scroll to the bottom, the grid refreshes itself and the scroll thumb jumps up to a position near the top of the scroll bar.  I understand that this is because pgAdmin4 only loads a fixed number of records.  When I try to scroll down further than that number, pgAdmin4 loads the next batch of records and repositions the thumb to the top of the newly loaded result lines.

There is a parameter somewhere that controls the number of records initially loaded into pgAdmin4's result grid.  I once had that value set to 10000000 (ten million).  Apparently, somewhere it got reset to its default value.  Now, I can't find it.  Where is that parameter?

Comment: Good luck with ten million. In my PGadmin 4 ver 3.3 in the Query Tool the task bar says "No Limit" for rows. The more I move down the results the more I get to see. Now I'm tired of doing that ....

Comment: When you drag the scroll thumb to the bottom of the bar, does the grid show you the last row in your result set, or does it thumb bounce back up to near the top of the scroll bar?  That's the behavior I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: This question is already answered in https://superuser.com/questions/1449833/pgadmin-4-data-ouput-tab-allows-only-1000-rows

Answer (score 2):

I found it.  It's in config.py.  On my machine, it's in C:/Program Files (x86)/pgAdmin4/v3.2/web.  The line is

```
ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 1000
```

I changed that value to 10000000 and got the behavior I want.

Comment: That's handy to know thanks. On some systems might need to reduce the count. I've up voted your answer.